Earbuds won't work in iPhone if connected to locked MacBook
I am having the following issue: I have the soundcore Liberty 4 earbuds connected to both my iPhone and my MacBook Air. If my MBA is locked (with the lid down), then my earbuds will not play anything on my iPhone, even though  they are connected and apparently the track is playing. As soon as I lift the Macbook's lid the earbuds play the audio.
Has anyone experienced this, or does anyone know how to fix it?
